# Writing a cookie from a static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a static class in my solution that is basically use a helper/ultility class.

In it I have the following static method:

```
// Set the user
    public static void SetUser(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        User NewUser = new User { Name = String.Format("{0}{1}", FirstName, LastName) };
        HttpCookie UserName = new HttpCookie("PressureName") { Value = NewUser.Name, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60) };       

    }
```

User is a simple class that contains:

```
  String _name = string.Empty;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
```

Everything works up until the point where I try to write the cookie "PressureName" and insert the value in it from NewUser.Name. From stepping through the code it appears that the cookie is never being written.

Am I making an obvious mistake? I'm still very amateur at c# and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating the cookie object is not enough to have it sent to the browser. You have to add it to the Response object also.

As you are in a static method, you don't have direct access to the page context and it's `Response` property. Use the `Current` property to access the Context of the current page from the static method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(UserName);
```