# unable to change cookie value set in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, cookies

I have an `<asp:CheckBox OnClick="">` set to a JavaScript function that performs the following:

```
document.cookie = "cv0_value=1";
```

I am checking this value within the .Net code-behind in the following manner and all appears to be working fine.

```
cv0_value = Request.Cookies["cv0_value"].Value == "0" ? false : true;
```

The issue is that when I attempt to later reset the value in the .Net code-behind it does not appear to affect the cookie.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cv0_value"].Value = "0";
```

When checking the value again in the code-behind I find that it is still set to the original value set in the JavaScript.

I have also tried to repeatedly call the Page_Load method, checking the Request and Response.  Despite setting the Response with the updated value when the Page_Load is called again the Request contains the original value.

As discussed in the comments below I believed the issue may be due to referencing from a static method but I found that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901760/writing-a-cookie-from-a-static-class) addresses the issue.  Since I am already referring to HttpContext.Current.Response it does not appear to be the problem in my instance.

Can someone explain what might be going on?

Comment: At what point in the request cycle are you changing the value?

Comment: The value is being changed via a call from the Page_Init.  The form is a collection of user controls that are being rendered.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set the value, make sure you save it.

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cv0_value"]
if (cookie != null)
{
   cookie.Value ="0";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
}
```

Comment: Is it *this* simple?  I'll get back to you after I try it.  Thanks.

Comment: +1. @McArthey, yes it is - use Response for response data... in general you should treat everything in Request as read only (since it came from client and will never go back) and everything in Response as more or less write-only as it is main purpose to send changes to client.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work.  Thanks for the clarification on Response and Request, though.

Comment: I've called your code above from the Page_Load.  The cv0_value has previously been set to "1".  Reloading the page multiple times does not result in the value changing to "0".

Comment: Are you sure your javascript isn't firing again and resetting the value? Can you show more of your code? Because what I showed will work.

Comment: I had that thought but I have a break in the JavaScript and it is not hitting the break.  I will double-check and add more info as possible.

Comment: For the button that I am using to submit the form after adding the modified cookie to the HttpContext.Current.Response I have a PostBackUrl specified.  Could this be causing the loss of the value?

Comment: Just noticed that my expire value is set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}.  Hmm.

Comment: cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); or whatever period you want. Do that after you set the value and before you save

Comment: Checking the debugger shows the value is set in Form1:Page_Load.  Hitting submit and directing to the PostBackUrl (Form2) and immediately checking HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cv0_value"] in Form2:Page_Init shows the values are no longer set.